# Can i3's assign be used to move a program to the scratchpad?

Tags: i3

I'm trying to move a window a workspace. Is

```
assign [class="^konsole$" title="^__scratch__"] → scratchpad
```

sufficient to move a term to the scratchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, to move a window to the scratch pad you must use `for_window`. It's unlike other workspaces in that regard,

```
for_window [class="^konsole$" title="^__scratch__"] move scratchpad
```

Then you can use `i3-msg scratchpad show` to see it.